# How to sort files in Windows explorer in custom order?

Tags: windows, filesystems, sorting

I have a great deal of folders. Each contains more than 30 files. I’d like to sort these files in a custom order. How do I create a custom order and have it sorted out the files the way I want?

I was wondering if there’s any function that would let me create my custom order and have it imported to get the sorting done in a certain way for each folder?

Comment: Programmers can do so by writing a shell extension that provides a new data column you could then use for sorting. But writing such a shell extensions requires a lot of time and work and just for sorting a few files the effort would be way too high. You better check if one of the other columns already uses the data so that the sort order is how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I create a custom order and have it sort the files the way I want?

Unfortunately, I think you are pretty much limited to whatever Explorer provides (i.e. single attributes from a predefined list).

Note that you can enable additional (single) attribute options for item sorting/grouping with *Right-Click -> Sort by/Group by -> More...*

Answer (score 0):

Windows File Explorer supports sorting by up to at least four properties in ascending or descending order. You can easily set up the sort order as you like for each folder type (e.g. General Items, Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos) using the free tool [WinSetView](https://lesferch.github.io/WinSetView/) on GitHub.